# ListView expanders are reset on Filter Search

Tags: wpf, listview, filter, viewmodel, expander

I've set up a simply WPF ListView bound to a view model, ListView uses a CollectionViewSource to sort the items based on various properties to dynamically create a ListView hierarchy - this works nicely.

I've also added a filter to allow for instance searching of the ListView - this also works well.

The problem I have is that when the user types some text into the search box, the search work, but it closes all of the expanders.

Every time a letter is typed into the search box the all expanders are again closed.

This is very annoying for the user, is there any way that the expander state can remain untouched during and after the search?

The WPF routine puts dogs into various groups.

Dog Class:

```
    public partial class Dogs : ViewModelBase
{

    //Group one nesting level
    private string _l1grouping;
    public string L1grouping
    {
        get
        {
            return _l1grouping;
        }
        set
        {
            _l1grouping = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(L1grouping));
        }
    }

    //Group two nesting level
    private string _l2grouping;
    public string L2grouping
    {
        get
        {
            return _l2grouping;
        }
        set
        {
            _l2grouping = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(L2grouping));
        }
    }

    //Group three nesting level
    private string _l3grouping;
    public string L3grouping
    {
        get
        {
            return _l3grouping;
        }
        set
        {
            _l3grouping = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(L3grouping));
        }
    }

    //Name
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set
        {
            if (_name != value)
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

View model class:

```
    class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ICollectionView DogsCollectionView { get; }

    private ObservableCollection<Dogs> _dogs = new ObservableCollection<Dogs>();

    public ObservableCollection<Dogs> Dogs
    {
        get => _dogs;
        set
        {
            if (value != _dogs)
            {
                _dogs = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Dogs));
            }
        }
    }

    private string _dogFilter = string.Empty;
    public string DogFilter
    {
        get
        {
            return _dogFilter;
        }
        set
        {
            _dogFilter = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DogFilter));
            DogsCollectionView.Refresh();
        }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    //Constructor
    {
        DogsCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_dogs);

        //Set up filter
        DogsCollectionView.Filter = FilterBrowserItems;

        //Set up grouping
        DogsCollectionView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription(nameof(SaveExpanderState.Dogs.L1grouping)));
        DogsCollectionView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription(nameof(SaveExpanderState.Dogs.L2grouping)));
        DogsCollectionView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription(nameof(SaveExpanderState.Dogs.L3grouping)));
    }

    private bool FilterBrowserItems(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Dogs check)
        {
            string nametocheck = check.Name.ToLower();
            return nametocheck.Contains(DogFilter.ToLower());
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Code behind that create the model:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    MainWindowViewModel DogViewModel
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DogViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();

        DogViewModel.Dogs.Add(new Dogs() { Name = "Max", L1grouping = "Large",  L2grouping = "Brown", L3grouping = "Fast" }); ;
        DogViewModel.Dogs.Add(new Dogs() { Name = "Bob", L1grouping = "Small", L2grouping = "Brown", L3grouping = "Slow" });
        DogViewModel.Dogs.Add(new Dogs() { Name = "Fido", L1grouping = "Large", L2grouping = "Brown", L3grouping = "Fast" });
        DogViewModel.Dogs.Add(new Dogs() { Name = "Brian", L1grouping = "Small", L2grouping = "Brown", L3grouping = "Fast" });
        DogViewModel.Dogs.Add(new Dogs() { Name = "Steve", L1grouping = "Large", L2grouping = "Black", L3grouping = "Fast" });
        DogViewModel.Dogs.Add(new Dogs() { Name = "Emma", L1grouping = "Large", L2grouping = "Black", L3grouping = "Slow" });
        DogViewModel.Dogs.Add(new Dogs() { Name = "Shep", L1grouping = "Large", L2grouping = "Black", L3grouping = "Fast" });
        DogViewModel.Dogs.Add(new Dogs() { Name = "Lassy", L1grouping = "Large", L2grouping = "White", L3grouping = "Fast" });
        DogViewModel.Dogs.Add(new Dogs() { Name = "Burt", L1grouping = "Large", L2grouping = "White", L3grouping = "Fast" });
        DogViewModel.Dogs.Add(new Dogs() { Name = "Siggy", L1grouping = "Small", L2grouping = "White", L3grouping = "Fast" });
        DogViewModel.Dogs.Add(new Dogs() { Name = "Heidi", L1grouping = "Small", L2grouping = "Black and White", L3grouping = "Fast" });
        DogViewModel.Dogs.Add(new Dogs() { Name = "Loki", L1grouping = "Large", L2grouping = "Yellow", L3grouping = "Fast" });

        ListViewDogs.DataContext = DogViewModel;

        FilterBoxText.DataContext = DogViewModel;
    }
}
```

and XAML for window:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                        Margin="10">
                <TextBlock Text="Filter: " />
                <TextBox x:Name="FilterBoxText"
                         Width="330"
                         Text="{Binding DogFilter, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            </StackPanel>

        </StackPanel>
        <ListView Name="ListViewDogs"
                  Margin="10,10,10,10"
                  Height="370"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding DogsCollectionView}"
                  IsTextSearchEnabled="False"
                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </WrapPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <Expander>
                                            <Expander.Header>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                            </Expander.Header>
                                            <ItemsPresenter />
                                        </Expander>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>
            
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Thanks, I'd appreciate some advise.

Comment: Maybe Bind the IsExpanded property

Comment: Would that be possible, the expanders are created dynamically by theCollectionViewSource, the only place I could think of adding a bind to IsExpanded is in the ControlTemplate but that would apply to every expander at the same time...

Comment: Why ? The Binding on the name is in the control template but is not the same for every items. I know it's possible if you have a boolean for each item, I just don't know if it's the right way to do it

Comment: DataContext of the expander is not Dog class, so it will be quite challenge to bind IsExpanded to the correct object.

Comment: Are any mistakes in my code? I can't believe this is the default way WPF works, I can't imagine any situation where the search should keep collapsing all the expanders each time the user types - I'm sure this would annoy the users a lot!

Comment: OK, so the problem is that when the filter is updated the code runs DogsCollectionView.Refresh(); - this rebuild the ListView resetting the expanders... Is it possible to refresh the listview in some way without completely rebuilding it?